# Traceback driving me crazy, can't seem to find the source where to debug

Tags: python, django, exception

I have gone through my templates making sure there is no trace of where this code can be found and now ultimately asking for help from the stackoverflow community

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 150, in get_response
   response = callback(request, **param_dict)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 19, in page_not_found
   return http.HttpResponseNotFound(t.render(RequestContext(request, {'request_path': request.path})))

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 123, in render
   return self._render(context)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
   return self.nodelist.render(context)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
   bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
   return node.render(context)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 127, in render
   return compiled_parent._render(context)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
   return self.nodelist.render(context)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
   bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
   return node.render(context)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 311, in render
   return self.nodelist_true.render(context)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
   bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
   return node.render(context)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 313, in render
   return self.nodelist_false.render(context)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
   bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
   return node.render(context)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 313, in render
   return self.nodelist_false.render(context)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
   bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
   return node.render(context)

 File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 450, in render
   raise e

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'dashboard_follow_user' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.


<WSGIRequest
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{'__cfduid': 'd8e6bd680abeae8bf20e0b04bab2bf6c01340266740',
'__utma': '252251985.852406610.1340266743.1341240383.1341474269.15',
'__utmb': '252251985.1.10.1341474269',
'__utmc': '252251985',
'__utmz': '252251985.1340266743.1.1.utmcsr=facebook.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/l.php',
'csrftoken': 'acdd7043eb39d9c14a3954786986512b',
'sessionid': '53868fdef6c96037ee26cf62fca1de9b'},
META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '',
'CONTENT_TYPE': '',
'CSRF_COOKIE': 'acdd7043eb39d9c14a3954786986512b',
'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip',
'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP': '62.95.0.45',
'HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY': 'SE',
'HTTP_CF_VISITOR': '{"scheme":"http"}',
'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
'HTTP_COOKIE': 'csrftoken=acdd7043eb39d9c14a3954786986512b; __cfduid=d8e6bd680abeae8bf20e0b04bab2bf6c01340266740; __utma=252251985.852406610.1340266743.1341240383.1341474269.15; __utmz=252251985.1340266743.1.1.utmcsr=facebook.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/l.php; sessionid=53868fdef6c96037ee26cf62fca1de9b; __utmb=252251985.1.10.1341474269; __utmc=252251985',
'HTTP_HOST': 'myapp.com',
'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)',
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '62.95.0.45, 173.245.49.189',
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http',
'HTTP_X_HEROKU_DYNOS_IN_USE': '1',
'HTTP_X_HEROKU_QUEUE_DEPTH': '0',
'HTTP_X_HEROKU_QUEUE_WAIT_TIME': '1',
'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': '173.245.49.189',
'HTTP_X_REQUEST_START': '1341474274655',
'HTTP_X_VARNISH': '958793214',
'PATH_INFO': u'/favicon.ico/',
'QUERY_STRING': '',
'RAW_URI': '/favicon.ico/',
'REMOTE_ADDR': '173.245.49.189',
'REMOTE_PORT': '80',
'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
'SERVER_NAME': 'myapp.com',
'SERVER_PORT': '80',
'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/0.12.2',
'gunicorn.socket': <socket._socketobject object at 0x3e24520>,
'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7fb5a0518270>,
'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper at 0x3422188>,
'wsgi.input': <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x3c02610>,
'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
'wsgi.multithread': False,
'wsgi.run_once': False,
'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

Comment: what's the url pattern defined for 'dashboard_follow_user' in your urls.py ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have in your template:

```
{% url dashboard_follow_user something %}
```

where something is an empty string "", while your urls.py probably says something like:

```
(r"/something/(?P<id>\d+)$"), "myview", {}, "dashboard_follow_user")
```

And it simply expects an `int` or something else, but not empty string("").

The reason for this stack trace is that this is the usual stack when rendering template elements, which are rendered one by one.